# Is it valid to use constexpr for aliasing functions?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constexpr

Lets assume that I have a function like this:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
T convert(U&& u) {
//...
}
```

I wanted to create some aliases for this function for different types, to make function calls simpler. Obviously, we cannot use `using` here because it is a function, not a type. So, I tried using `constexpr` and it works just fine like this:

```
constexpr auto convertAtoB = convert<B,A>;
//...
auto b = convertAtoB(b);
```

But I wonder if this syntax is valid according to the C++ Standard. Even though I cannot think of anything that makes this code invalid, I just want to be sure that I'm not missing anything. Especially if the function itself if **not** `constexpr` (like `convert` here), I think this code should be valid.

Any idea?

Comment: Your use of `U&&` as the argument type is confusing things, I think. Why not just `U`?

Comment: But  I guess the `constexpr` qualifier applies to the function's **address** rather than to its operation or return type.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong here either.

Comment: The only problem I can think of is if second template argument type is correct? Maybe `constexpr auto convertAtoB = convert<B, const A& >;` is more proper? Since we do not know anything more it is hard to tell.

Comment: @AdrianMole yea, it surely applies to function address and that's why I think it should be fine. I somehow curious if it can create problem for linking or not, but I guess it should be ok there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see nothing that would make your use of `constexpr` here invalid or ill-formed. That `constexpr` specifier is effectively being applied to the function's **address**, so whether or not the function *itself*, or its return value, are `constexpr` seems irrelevant.

In your `constexpr auto convertAtoB = convert<B,A>;` line, the `convertAtoB` is effectively declared as a function pointer, like this:

```cpp
constexpr B (*convertAtoB)(A&& u) = &convert;
```

Semantically, it is no different from something like the following:

```cpp
int iVal = 303;
constexpr int* iPtr = &iVal;
```

Here, although `iVal` is not `constexpr` (nor even `const`), its address *can* be; hence, the `constexpr` specifier is valid on `iPtr`.

Answer (score 3):

According to [[expr.const].5](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#5) the expression `convert<B,A>` is indeed a core constant expression because it matches **none** of the long list of properties that would make it **not so**:

- (5.1) this ([expr.prim.this]), except ...
- (5.2) a control flow that ...
- (5.3) an invocation of a non-constexpr function [**your example is not an invocation**]
- (5.4) an invocation of an undefined constexpr function;
- (5.5) an invocation of an instantiated constexpr function that is not constexpr-suitable;
- (5.6) an invocation of a virtual function ([class.virtual]) for an object whose dynamic type is constexpr-unknown;
- (5.7) an expression that would exceed the implementation-defined limits (see [implimits]);
- (5.8) an operation that would have undefined behavior as specified in [intro] through [cpp], excluding [dcl.attr.assume];73
- (5.9) an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion unless it is applied to ...
- (5.10) an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that is applied to a glvalue that refers to a non-active member of a union or a subobject thereof;
- (5.11) an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that is applied to an object with an indeterminate value;
- (5.12) an invocation of an implicitly-defined copy/move constructor or copy/move assignment operator for a union whose active member (if any) is mutable, unless the lifetime of the union object began within the evaluation of E;
- (5.13) in a lambda-expression, a reference to this or to a variable with automatic storage duration defined outside that lambda-expression, where the reference would be an odr-use ([basic.def.odr], [expr.prim.lambda]);
- (5.14) a conversion from type cv void* to a pointer-to-object type;
- (5.15) a reinterpret_cast ([expr.reinterpret.cast]);
- (5.16) a modification of an object ([expr.ass], [expr.post.incr], [expr.pre.incr]) unless ...
- (5.17) an invocation of a destructor ([class.dtor]) or a function call whose postfix-expression names a pseudo-destructor ([expr.call]), in either case for an object whose lifetime did not begin within the evaluation of E;
- (5.18) a new-expression ([expr.new]), unless the selected allocation function is a replaceable global allocation function ([new.delete.single], [new.delete.array]) and the allocated storage is deallocated within the evaluation of E;
- (5.19) a delete-expression ([expr.delete]), unless it deallocates a region of storage allocated within the evaluation of E;
- (5.20) a call to an instance of std​::​allocator​::​allocate ([allocator.members]), unless the allocated storage is deallocated within the evaluation of E;
- (5.21) a call to an instance of std​::​allocator​::​deallocate ([allocator.members]), unless it deallocates a region of storage allocated within the evaluation of E;
- (5.22) an await-expression ([expr.await]);
- (5.23) a yield-expression ([expr.yield]);
- (5.24) a three-way comparison ([expr.spaceship]), relational ([expr.rel]), or equality ([expr.eq]) operator where the result is unspecified;
- (5.25) a throw-expression ([expr.throw]);
- (5.26) a dynamic_cast ([expr.dynamic.cast]) or typeid ([expr.typeid]) expression on a glvalue that refers to an object whose dynamic type is constexpr-unknown or that would throw an exception;
- (5.27) an asm-declaration ([dcl.asm]);
- (5.28) an invocation of the va_arg macro ([cstdarg.syn]);
- (5.29) a non-constant library call ([defns.nonconst.libcall]); or
- (5.30) a goto statement ([stmt.goto]).

(or this list of conditions where the status is unspecified)

- (5.31) an operation that has undefined behavior as specified in [library] through [thread],
- (5.32) an invocation of the va_start macro ([cstdarg.syn]), or
- (5.33) a statement with an assumption ([dcl.attr.assume]) whose converted conditional-expression, if evaluated where the assumption appears, would not disqualify E from being a core constant expression and would not evaluate to true.

---

In conclusion, none of these apply. The closest, (5.3), mentions a non-constexpr function, but requires the function to be invoked. Your expression, however does not contain the actual invocation and is therefore a core constant expression, a `constexpr`.